# How to install as3 corelib to activate png encoder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to add a save option to a coloring book app but so far I've been absolutely stumped with how to activate the as3 corelib even though I downloaded it. Now to be clear, I'm a novice in the world of programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link of where you downloaded? The answer depends on whether you got some **.as** files or you got an **.swc**. Also which IDE are you using (Flash CS, Animate CC, FlashBuilder, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Actionscript has native jpeg and png compression; no need to use as3corelib or Flex:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS4768145595f94108-17913eb4136eaab51c7-8000.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/PNGEncoderOptions.html

```
// Compress a BitmapData object as a PNG file. 
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,480,false,0x00FF00); 
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0,0,640,480), new flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions(), byteArray);
```

Comment: But then how do i use the save button to activate this?

Comment: This example shows you how to make the raw data of a jpeg/png file from a BitmapData. You'll then have to write this raw data into a file (with File if you are working in AIR, or FileReference in Flash).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use an external library if you are using flex 3 or later. The [`mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/PNGEncoder.html) class is available for FP 9 / Air 1.1

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Flash Builder:

Take as3corelib.swc and copy it into your project's `lib` folder.  If you don't have a `lib` folder in your project, create one and register it by right-clicking the project > properties > Flex Build Path > Add SWC... button.

If you're using Flash Professional:

Go to File > Actionscript settings, Library path tab, `+` button, and add the path to your as3corelib.swc (ideally a sub-folder of your project).

Comment: Thanks man i havent really had the time to check but ill try it today and see if it works.